# Need to add a new condition to a SPLIT(FLATTEN(SEQUENCE Function (Google Sheets)?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, split, sequence

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SEQUENCE(1, J2, 1, 1)&"*"&"*"&SEQUENCE(J3)), "\*"))
```

Above is the formula.

I need to add in a third column which will sequence between 1 & 3.

Essentially, I want the table that is already built to be repeated 3 times, starting from 1 and ending with 3.

[GOOGLE SHEET - Help](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XQE3tJSIUjRhP2mxUoHEBJt0jWAJcd3zfhJr_owFzvQ/edit?usp=sharing/)

[image: FORMULA]

I tried adding a 3rd sequence within the formula, and it kept #REFing

Answer (score 0):

You can simply apply the same reasoning another time (before splitting) and you'll get:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(FLATTEN(SEQUENCE(1,J2)&"*"&SEQUENCE(J3))&"*"&SEQUENCE(1,J4))),"*"))
```

I entered the formula in z!A2.

Comment: I only learned these formulas last month and am making progress. I tried exactly what you did, but I wrote SEQUENCE(J4,1) instead of SEQUENCE(1,J4)